# Increase the number of Dask workers in Kubernetes deployment

Tags: python, azure, docker, kubernetes, dask

I have in Azure a Kubernetes cluster that deploys three Docker containers: a Flask server, a Dask Scheduler and a Dask Worker. This works fine, now I need to deploy N workers instead of one.

This is the yaml file:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: img-python
  namespace: default
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: cont-python
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: cont-python
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: cont-flask
          image: xxx.azurecr.io/myimage:latest
          command: ["gunicorn"]
          args: ["-t", "7200", "-b", "0.0.0.0:5000", "--reload", "app.front.app:app"]
          ports:
            - containerPort: 5000
          volumeMounts:
            - name: volcode
              mountPath: /code
        - name: cont-scheduler
          image: xxx.azurecr.io/myimage:latest
          command: ["dask-scheduler"]
          ports:
            - containerPort: 8786
            - containerPort: 8787
        - name: cont-worker
          image: xxx.azurecr.io/myimage:latest
          workingDir: /code
          command: ["dask-worker"]
          args: ["scheduler:8786"]
          volumeMounts:
            - name: volcode
              mountPath: /code
      volumes:
        - name: volcode
          azureFile:
            shareName: py-code
            readOnly: false
```

I looked at the `kubectl scale` command however it seems to scale the entire cluster, not only specifically the worker's container.

How to specify the number of workers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The yaml file specifies a deployment, which can be scaled horizontally to any number of pods (either by setting the `spec.replicas` in the yaml file or on the fly using `kubectl scale`)

**It is not possible to scale individual containers inside a pod** since pods are the smallest deployable units of computing that can be managed by Kubernetes

From the [docs](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/pods/#using-pods):

> Each Pod is meant to run a single instance of a given application. **If
> you want to scale your application horizontally (to provide more
> overall resources by running more instances), you should use multiple
> Pods**, one for each instance. In Kubernetes, this is typically referred
> to as replication. Replicated Pods are usually created and managed as
> a group by a workload resource and its controller.

Thus, to scale out the number of workers to 10 without scaling the server and scheduler, the worker needs to be a separate deployment (so that the worker is run it its own pod).

Comment: and the way to scale the workers is this? `kubectl scale --replicas=3 -f worker.yaml`

Comment: Yes, that will scale the resources defined in `worker.yaml` to 3 replicas. Please see details in the [kubectl cheatsheet](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/kubectl/cheatsheet/#scaling-resources)